how to specify additional options to openconnect when invoked via nmcli?
I use mlcli to connect to a VPN, like this: nmcli conn --ask up myVPN. Under the hood this invokes openconnect:
\_ bash
|   \_ nmcli conn --ask up myVPN
|       \_ /usr/sbin/openconnect --authenticate myVPN.xyz

This used to work until recently when the VPN operator has started requesting certain value of the User-Agent HTTP header sent in the initial HTTPS connection when connecting to the VPN server.
The openconnect command has the --useragent=STRING. Is there a way how to modify the VPN profile to pass it to the openconnect command ?

In theory, the user agent can be added to the vpn.data property of the VPN profile:
nmcli c modify id myVPN +vpn.data useragent=FooBar

however it did not do the trick for me.
